# Remove automatic P tag on static block

Tags: tinymce

how do i remove automatic `<p> tag` on static block or static page, which js file(s) should i edit?

and also i don't want to disable the wysiwyg editor

already check on js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js still no idea where is it

```
var settings = {
            mode : (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
            elements : this.id,
            theme : 'advanced',
            plugins : plugins,
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,
            convert_urls : false,
            relative_urls : false,
            content_css: this.config.content_css,
            custom_popup_css: this.config.popup_css,
            magentowidget_url: this.config.widget_window_url,
            magentoPluginsOptions: magentoPluginsOptions,
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

got the answer

```
var settings = {
            mode : (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
            elements : this.id,
            theme : 'advanced',
            plugins : plugins,
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,
            convert_urls : false,
            relative_urls : false,
            forced_root_block : '', /* <-- Add this setting */
            content_css: this.config.content_css,
            custom_popup_css: this.config.popup_css,
            magentowidget_url: this.config.widget_window_url,
            magentoPluginsOptions: magentoPluginsOptions,
```

got from here

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902625/remove-automatic-p-tag-on-static-block/22913138

Comment: Would help if you mentioned the file where to add this code